# Как брутфорсить AES?

Tags: python, aes

В общем есть строка (просто пример):

```
{"data":"ZbGOHhmbCr6SaaQUdMR7cMTXShhzlzpWVqXHA==","iv":"5y1WPN7nqaahg==","salt":"TaKtjVSlsplJKyKn0FzGrJ42BowgeFFssSx1k="}'
```

Для дешифровки этой строки есть вот такой код

```
import json
try:
    data = json.loads(info)
    password = passwd
    salt = base64.b64decode(data['salt'])
    vault = base64.b64decode(data['data'])
    iv = base64.b64decode(data['iv'])
except:
    return None

key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), salt, 10000, 32)

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
decrypted_block = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv).decrypt(vault)
try:
    if decrypted_block.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').__contains__('"findThis":"'):
        something = decrypted_block.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').find('"findThis":"') + 12
        something2 = decrypted_block.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').find('","numberOfAccounts"') - 43
        decryptedData = decrypted_block.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')[something:][:something2]
        return {'data': decryptedData, 'password': passwd}
    else:
        return None
except:
    return None
```

Я пытался сделать Брутфорсер, но он может перебрать 100-500 паролей в секунду да и в питоне очень плохо разбираюсь, есть-ли вариант как это все дело ускорить до нескольких миллионов комбинаций в секунду как тут https://github.com/sebastien-riou/aes-brute-force

Comment: Нет, на питоне это невозможно. разве что вы напишите для питона специальную библиотеку на C, которая будет практически повторять тот код, который вы привели в качестве примера. Потому как необходимо по максимуму использовать аппаратное ускорение AES в процессорах intel. Которое вряд ли используется в стандартной библиотеке. Ну и полностью весь цикл перебора должен быть собственно в C, что бы питон только загрузил туда исходные данные и сам более ничего не делал, потому как питон очень медленный язык

Comment: А еще вы обратили внимание, что код в том гите перебирает только 4 байта из возможного ключа. И на это у него уходит 20 секунд. На перебор полных 16 байт ключа на одном ядре уйдет 5629499534213120 секунд (178 млн лет). А пароль в ключ у вас превращается с помощью sha256. А у таких алгоритмов как sha огромный лавинный эффект и изменение одного бита в пароле приведет к изменению непредсказуемым образом всех 16 байт ключа. Так что вам на каждый пароль надо выполнить 2 операции, сначала sha, потом aes, что минимум в 2 раза дольше, чем просто aes

Comment: @Mike не просто sha, а pbkdf2_hmac — функция которая по определению должна быть медленной

Comment: Забыл упомянуть то что IV SALT известны, неизвестен только ключ, есть ли готовый софт. 178 млн лет я потерплю